# want to write MS-Access like query builder in c?#

Tags: c#, parsing

we want to create MS-Access LIKE query parser where user can create complex queries having joins?

any thoughts on design in c#?

Comment: You're going to have to rephrase that

Comment: How about parsing SQL like strings to Linq? Read up on Linq Expressions. See here for a sample: [SqlLinq: Taking LINQ to SQL in the Other Direction](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/SqlLinq.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at SQL Server Express (2008 or 2008 r2) and the management studio. With the Management Studio you can already create complex queries with joins (View Designer is an example). If you are looking for an end user product then I would look at reporting services that allows users to create reports and query data directly.

Comment: my app users are somewhat know SQL and hey want to create dynamic query and we want to write some light weight application in c#